# How to remove an existing organization?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I created a fabric network using Raft. It has a channel:`mychannel`. `Org1`, `Org2` and `Org3` belong to this channel.

Now, I want to remove `Org3` from `mychannel`.
How can I remove it?

Should I update the config block or issue a CRL?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there is no any curl command as such, you just have to manually do it my removing that particular organisation from config.json and then you can upgrade your chaincode. ref- https://medium.com/@kctheservant/remove-an-organization-from-a-running-fabric-network-55f52cd0a012